# Can I manage the entity status in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, frameworks, entity, status

Recently, I am trying to use NHibernate in my project.   see the code below

```
var _sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        var _session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        var user = new User() {UserName = "carl", Gender = 1};
        _session.Save(user);
        _session.Delete(user);
        _session.Flush();
        _session.Close();
        _sessionFactory.Dispose();
```

the  NHibernate  will save the user into db and then delete it from db. I know the code is kind weird, But I really want NHibernate know that you don't really need to access db twice. the Entity Framework will work different, it will switch status of user object in memory, when do a flush, it will access db to persistant it.of course the user which status is marked as deleted will not be persistanted. so no db access needed here. that's what i want!!

Is there any one know that NHibernate have that interface to change the Entity Status like EF?

Comment: What's your mapping for the User class? Does it require a database roundtrip for the (presumed) id-key? Why are you persisting the object if you know you want to remove it? Why do you consider a single database call (delete) so expensive that you need to avoid it? Have you tried using a transaction which you rollback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason the entity is saved to the database at all is because you are presumeably using Identity id generation which forces NH to insert immediatly. If you use another strategy eg HiLo you would see what you expected.

Comment: You are right about the identity id! but after I set it to HiLo strategy, NHibernate still save it to db and delete from db. The reason is that NHiberate will save all the action into ActionQueue. when you flush the session. it will pull all the action and invoke it. I think it's not the best way to do it! NHibernate should track the status of entity and decide whether save it or not.

Comment: i think the reasoning behind this is, that there could be triggers, nhibernate.envers or some other thing which wants to know what happend. if you wrap this up in a transaction and rollback, nothing will be sent at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the identity id will trigger the insert on database, you can't help it. However changing to hi-lo still doesn't guarantee that the insert will not occur. The reason lies on NHibernate's ISession generation from NHibernateSessionFactory and the default FlushMode.

See section 9.7 from the NHibernate Reference where it explains the FlushMode mechanism. For your case you should set FlushMode to Never (`FlushMode.Never`) so that no behind-the-scenes Flushes occur.

Comment: I tried FlushMode.Never and it still Saved/Deleted with twice db access. I think that is exactly how  NHibernate build this function. There might be no way to get rid of db access in my code. NHibernate might manage the ORM by tracing every action of the code instead of the final status of the entity. in another word. if I write the stupid code as above. NHibernate  will follow it as stupid as I am.